# Presenting a sheet over a NavigationStack crashes on macOS but not iPadOS

Tags: macos, swiftui

I’m trying to present a sheet from a pushed view on a `NavigationStack` on macOS, but it crashes. The same code seems to behave as expected on iPadOS.

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView
        {
            List
            {
                Text("Foo")
                Text("Bar")
            }
            .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 200, ideal: 200)
        }
        detail:
        {
            NavigationStack
            {
                Text("The Detail")
                    .navigationTitle("Detail")
                    .toolbar
                    {
                        ToolbarItemGroup
                        {
                            NavigationLink(value: "New thing")
                            {
                                Label("New thing", systemImage: "plus")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: String.self)
                    { _ in
                        AddView()
                    }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct
AddView : View
{
    var
    body: some View
    {
        Text("new thing editor")
            .navigationTitle("New Thing")
            .toolbar
            {
                ToolbarItemGroup
                {
                    Button(action: { self.isPresentingSearch = true })
                    {
                        Label("Search Thing", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                    }
                }
            }
            .sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresentingSearch)
            {
                Text("Search Thing UI")
            }
    }
    
    @State  private var isPresentingSearch                  =   false
}
```

Clicking the magnifying glass to set `isPresentingSearch` true results in:

```
2023-02-14 19:09:55.539599-0800 TestSheet[34435:770832] [General] The window has been marked as needing another Update Constraints in Window pass, but it has already had more Update Constraints in Window passes than there are views in the window. 
<_TtC7SwiftUIP33_00AAB847C3060B4FF7A299E87C10010C23SheetPresentationWindow: 0x15610d0e0> 0x5c3 (1475) {{0, 0}, {97, 44}} en Future marking as needing Update Constraints in Window might be ignored.
2023-02-14 19:09:55.546262-0800 TestSheet[34435:770832] [General] The window has been marked as needing another Update Constraints in Window pass, but it has already had more Update Constraints in Window passes than there are views in the window. 
<_TtC7SwiftUIP33_00AAB847C3060B4FF7A299E87C10010C23SheetPresentationWindow: 0x15610d0e0> 0x5c3 (1475) {{0, 0}, {97, 44}} en
2023-02-14 19:09:55.551251-0800 TestSheet[34435:770832] [General] (
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a49f83e8 __exceptionPreprocess + 176
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00000001a4542ea8 objc_exception_throw + 60
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x00000001a49f828c +[NSException exceptionWithName:reason:userInfo:] + 0
    3   AppKit                              0x00000001a7c337a4 -[NSWindow(NSDisplayCycle) _postWindowNeedsUpdateConstraintsUnlessPostingDisabled] + 1844
    4   AppKit                              0x00000001a7c1d790 -[NSView _informContainerThatSubviewsNeedUpdateConstraints] + 64
    5   AppKit                              0x00000001a7c1d714 -[NSView setNeedsUpdateConstraints:] + 460
    6   SwiftUI                             0x00000001cb7944c8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_19 + 254512
    7   SwiftUI                             0x00000001cb764df4 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_19 + 60252
.
.
.
```

App project here: https://github.com/JetForMe/TestSheet

Answer (score 0):

**Update:**

This seems to have been fixed in macOS 13.3.

**Previous Workaround:**

One of the many crashes in SwiftUI for macOS 13 when using `NavigationSplitView` and `NavigationStack`.

You can work around this specific one by placing the `.sheet` outside of your `NavigationStack` and passing a binding, like so:

```
struct ContentView: View
{
    @State private var isPresentingSearch = false
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationSplitView {
            List {
                Text("Foo")
                Text("Bar")
            }
            .navigationSplitViewColumnWidth(min: 200, ideal: 200)
        } detail: {
            NavigationStack {
                Text("The Detail")
                    .navigationTitle("Detail")
                    .toolbar {
                        ToolbarItemGroup {
                            NavigationLink(value: "New thing") {
                                Label("New thing", systemImage: "plus")
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    .navigationDestination(for: String.self) { _ in
                        AddView(isPresentingSearch: $isPresentingSearch)
                    }
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: self.$isPresentingSearch) {
            Text("Search Thing UI")
        }
    }
}

struct AddView : View
{
    @Binding var isPresentingSearch:Bool
    
    var body: some View {
        Text("new thing editor")
            .navigationTitle("New Thing")
            .toolbar {
                ToolbarItemGroup {
                    Button(action: { self.isPresentingSearch = true }) {
                        Label("Search Thing", systemImage: "magnifyingglass")
                    }
                }
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'll try this. It does seem to be fixed in 13.3 beta. Hopefully they back-port it (but I doubt it).